# VBA to assign data according of two columns from workbook 1 to workbook 2

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, vlookup, xlookup

I need a help and your wide experiences please.

Lets imagine a case:

- Three Workbooks exists: Workbook1 & Workbook2 & Workbook3
- The Workbook1 & Workbook 2 has two same columns: ColumnA & ColumnB (for Workbook1) &  ColumnAA & ColumnBB (for Workbook2)
- All data are unsorded.
- All columns has a different number of rows.
- Macro in Workbook3 will be run and assign data from Workbook1 according of ColumnA & ColumnB to Workbook2 to ColumnCC & ColumnDD.
- No auxiliary columns are allowed.

I am solivng it now by the simple VLOOKUP macro column by column. But I am still geting same values in ColumnCC & ColumnDD. It means that a all found values are same according of first found value in ColumnC & ColumnD but there are different values in that columns after all. And I stucked just here because I do not know how to solve it by macro.

The result what I need to get on is shown on attached picture below.

Curently I am try to solve it using a combination of the functions IF  & VLOOKUP but i do not know how to build the macro fot this case of two functions and I did not find a relevant example to rewrite it by analogous.

`=IF(B:B="ano";VLOOKUP(A:A;[Workbook1.xlsx]Sheet1!$A:$D; 3; 0); "")`

[Result example & combined formula IF+VLOOKUP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIFJD.png)

I would be grateful for your help or find another simple way using a macro.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Vlookup returns the first result. You're saying that there are also different values for the key in ColumnA. But I can't see any example of  that and desired output in the example you provided. What should happen? Wouldn't solution be just to connect and deduplicated the two tables? Or is the second table only a subset you want to select?

Comment: so to clarify the vlookup is working. but in workbook one there are multiple values for a given lookup value, "5T4 8164" for example may have multiple values in workbook1  but the vlookup is returning just the first one and you want to return more than the first one?  how do you propose for the multiple values to be displayed?  If this is correct it would be good to update the image to show multiple values in workbook 1 and how they are to be handled in workbook 2, then we can advise better

Answer (score 0):

Example which hopefully can get you start.
[image]

Book1:2 is your Workbook2.xlsx - Book1:1 is your Workbook1.xlsx 
On both workbooks, the rows value under HDR2 (column B) is either blank or "ano".
 Nothing else, no rows with value other than "ano" under HDR2 in both workbooks.

The expected result in Workbook2.xlsx :
[image]

Regarding the blue and yellow color as seen from the image above, 
there is no result in HDR3 and HDR4 in book2 - because 
Blue : fff has no ano in book2 although fff has ano in book1.
Yellow : although ggg has ano in book2, but ggg in book1 has no ano.

If that's the kind of result you expect, the code is something like this :

```
Sub test()
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim rgWb1 As Range: Dim rgWb2 As Range
Dim cWb1 As Range: Dim cWb2 As Range
Dim concWb1 As String: Dim concWb2 As String

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1.xslx") 'change as needed
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2.xslx") 'change as needed

    With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed
        Set rgWb1 = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
    End With

    With wb2.Sheets("Sheet2") 'change as needed
        Set rgWb2 = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1)
    End With

For Each cWb2 In rgWb2.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
concWb2 = cWb2.Offset(0, -1).Value & cWb2.Value
    For Each cWb1 In rgWb1.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        concWb1 = cWb1.Offset(0, -1).Value & cWb1.Value
        If concWb2 = concWb1 Then
            cWb2.Offset(0, 1).Value = cWb1.Offset(0, 1).Value
            cWb2.Offset(0, 2).Value = cWb1.Offset(0, 2).Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

The process:
It set the data range under HDR2 for both workbooks, as rgWb1 and rgWb2 variable. As the "rule" I've said before, since the rows under HDR2 will be only either blank or "ano" in both workbooks, so the code loop only to each cell (as cWb2 variable) which has value in rgWb2, concat the cWb2 value with the cell to the left value as concWb2.

Then it loop to each cell (as cWb1 variable) which has value in rgWb1 and also do the concat the cWb1 value with the cell to the left value as concWb1.

It check if concWb2 value = concWb1 value, then it put the value of cWb1.Offset(0, 1) to cWb2.Offset(0, 1) and put the value of cWb1.Offset(0, 2) to cWb2.Offset(0, 2).

FYI, with the "rule" for the rows under HDR2 in both workbooks like that, actually the code doesn't need to do the concatenate (concWb1 and concWb2). Anyway, I just have it to do the concatenate.

Please note, the code assumed that the data under HDR1 in both workbooks are all unique.

Comment: As I used your formula generally it works. I got a value in to the right columns for each found cells but unfortunately there is a problem because I have goten always first same found value for both of columns. The problem is that I have no unique data in the cells in the columns HDR3 & HDR4 what I am looking for. For example in your case you will always get 3 for each founded cell in HDR3 and ccc3 in HDR4 & it will be shown in Wb2 where I apply your code.
In my case what I have describes above there are also same values in the ColumnCC & the ColumnDD.

Comment: Sorry, if you have duplicate data in sheet1, then the code won't know which one to be put in columnCC and DD. Example, in sheet1 row 5 column A value "5T4 8166", col B value "ano", col C "100", col D "1234". Then in other row (say, row 27) column A again has "5T4 8166", col B value "ano" .... the difference, col C row 27 value is "500" and col D is "5678". So how the code know the one that need to be put in Sheet2 in row nth under CC and DD where row nth col A has "5T4 8166" and row nth col B has "ano" in Sheet2 ?

Comment: At first I thought that in sheet1, the data under colA is unique (unique ID), no duplicate value, consequently the rest of the data to the right (same row) belong only to this unique ID. Say in sheet1 row 5 col A value "5T4 8166", then row5 colB value is either blank or has "ano", while row5 colC and colD value doesn't matter. There is no more "5T4 8166" in the rest of the row under col A sheet1... only that row5 under colA has "5T4 8166" in sheet1.

Comment: When you check my example again the column A is always unique and the column B has a same values "ano".
According of column A & column B I would like to look for values from any other colums from C to nextone but data can be same from column C to the end.

Comment: ![Description via image](https://i.postimg.cc/RFwVkg7p/Excel-example.png)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this : _in your case you will always get 3 for each founded cell in HDR3 and ccc3 in HDR4_. Yes it of course always give 3 and ccc3 because what the sub read in sheet1, the row where the ccc is (col a) and has ano (col b), the value in col c is 3 and the value is ccc3. No matter how many times you run the sub, it will put the result 3 and ccc3 in sheet2. Except in sheet1 you change the value of row ccc, column c to (for example) 456 and column d to abc. Then when you run again the sub, it will give 456 and abc in sheet 2 for row with ccc.

Comment: The result image example show sheet2 result for ccc ano is 3 and ccc3 because what the code found in sheet1 ccc ano row has 3 and ccc3. Sheet 2 result for ddd ano is 4 and ddd4 because wha the code found in sheet 1, row ddd ano has 4 and ddd 4. Based on the data sheet1 sample image, What is actually should be the result show in sheet2 col c and d  where the row in col a and b is ddd and ano if not 4 and ddd4? Please CMIIW.

Comment: Hi... welll...I did not understand so I try your code use exactly on you example and it works well but in my data does not work... see picture...you will understand now.

(https://i.postimg.cc/cJmhk05F/Makro-Issue.png)

Comment: @Michael, I'm very sorry as I don't know why it repeat the resulted value (9). Please try to check to each range variable if it's correct or not by add a "helper" line, something like : `rgWb1.select`, step run it, and before the yellow indicator pass the `rgWb1.select` activate the workbook & the sheet first. Check also if `rgWb2.select` is correct. (continue)

Comment: And when the yellow past `concWb2` and `concWb1`, see what is the value of them in Locals window. Then finally, before the result writing, add a line `cWb1.Offset(0, 1).select` - before the yellow pass this line, activate wb1 and the sheet first, continue the yellow to pass this line, and see if it select the correct cell.